# Fatal signal 11 fault on Android Studio

Tags: c++, sqlite, android-studio

I have table in database that holds copy status and a function to check if the datas are copied.

```
bool ItemDatabase::getIsCopied() {
    bool iscopied;
    ofxSQLiteSelect sel = sqlite->select("iscopied")
            .from(TNAME_COPYSTATUS)
            .execute().begin();
    while(sel.hasNext()){
        iscopied = (bool) sel.getInt();
        sel.next();
    }
    return iscopied;
}
```

I have a function that encrypts data from an unencrypted table and copies it to another table. If the data is copied, the value of iscopied is changed to 1 in the database. This function is as follows.

```
void ItemDatabase::passPackTableToPackEncTable(){
    std::vector<std::string> datas;
    for (int a = 0; a < packdata_id.size(); a++) {
        ofxSQLiteSelect sel = sqlite->select("*")
                .from(TNAME_PACK)
                .where("id", packdata_id.at(a))
                .execute().begin();

        while (sel.hasNext()) {
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            datas.push_back(sel.getString());
            sel.next();
        }

        sqlite->update(TNAME_PACKENC)
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][0], aes->encrypt(datas.at(0)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][1], aes->encrypt(datas.at(1)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][2], aes->encrypt(datas.at(2)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][3], aes->encrypt(datas.at(3)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][4], aes->encrypt(datas.at(4)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][5], aes->encrypt(datas.at(5)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][6], aes->encrypt(datas.at(6)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][7], aes->encrypt(datas.at(7)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][8], aes->encrypt(datas.at(8)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][9], aes->encrypt(datas.at(9)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][10], aes->encrypt(datas.at(10)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][11], aes->encrypt(datas.at(11)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][12], aes->encrypt(datas.at(12)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][13], aes->encrypt(datas.at(13)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][14], aes->encrypt(datas.at(14)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][15], aes->encrypt(datas.at(15)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][16], aes->encrypt(datas.at(16)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][17], aes->encrypt(datas.at(17)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][18], aes->encrypt(datas.at(18)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][19], aes->encrypt(datas.at(19)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][20], aes->encrypt(datas.at(20)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][21], aes->encrypt(datas.at(21)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][22], aes->encrypt(datas.at(22)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][23], aes->encrypt(datas.at(23)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][24], aes->encrypt(datas.at(24)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][25], aes->encrypt(datas.at(25)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][26], aes->encrypt(datas.at(26)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][27], aes->encrypt(datas.at(27)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][28], aes->encrypt(datas.at(28)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][29], aes->encrypt(datas.at(29)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][30], aes->encrypt(datas.at(30)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][31], aes->encrypt(datas.at(31)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][32], aes->encrypt(datas.at(32)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][33], aes->encrypt(datas.at(33)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][34], aes->encrypt(datas.at(34)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][35], aes->encrypt(datas.at(35)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][36], aes->encrypt(datas.at(36)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][37], aes->encrypt(datas.at(37)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][38], aes->encrypt(datas.at(38)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][39], aes->encrypt(datas.at(39)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][40], aes->encrypt(datas.at(40)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][41], aes->encrypt(datas.at(41)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][42], aes->encrypt(datas.at(42)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][43], aes->encrypt(datas.at(43)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][44], aes->encrypt(datas.at(44)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][45], aes->encrypt(datas.at(45)))
                .use(columnname[TABLE_PACKENC][46], aes->encrypt(datas.at(46)))
                .where("id", packdata_id.at(a))
                .execute();
        datas.clear();
    }
    // makes iscopied = 1 in database
    sqlite->update(TNAME_COPYSTATUS)
            .use(columnname[TABLE_COPYSTATUS][0], 1)
            .execute();
}
```

I call this function when the application is starting.

```
if (getDatabaseInitialization() == 0) {
        createTables();
        populateTables();
        setDatabaseInitialization(1);
    } else {
        readDatabase();
    }

    if(!getIsCopied()){
        passPackTableToPackEncTable();
    }
```

I'm running a test like this to make sure old users don't lose their data. First of all, I change the line with the function to the comment line and run the application once. Then I delete the comment line and run the application again. The result I expected is that the data is encrypted successfully and the application runs, but the application fails. After a few tries, I found out what part of the application was failing, but I could not find out why. When I run it as I mentioned, it works for a = 0 in the function and gives an error.

```
08-24 14:00:12.700 15813-15924/com.nitragames.football.taso2016 A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 15924 (GLThread 1558)
08-24 14:00:12.810 383-383/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-24 14:00:12.810 383-383/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a53gxx/a53g:6.0.1/MMB29M/A500HXXS1CQC6:user/release-keys'
08-24 14:00:12.810 383-383/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '10'
08-24 14:00:12.810 383-383/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
08-24 14:00:12.810 383-383/? A/DEBUG: pid: 15813, tid: 15924, name: GLThread 1558  >>> com.nitragames.football.taso2016 <<<
08-24 14:00:12.810 383-383/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
08-24 14:00:12.850 383-383/? A/DEBUG:     r0 930cf12c  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 930cf12c
08-24 14:00:12.850 383-383/? A/DEBUG:     r4 b8958be0  r5 9c06c4ac  r6 930cf3c8  r7 930cef48
08-24 14:00:12.850 383-383/? A/DEBUG:     r8 00000000  r9 9d51f1b4  sl b88a7c08  fp 00000000
08-24 14:00:12.850 383-383/? A/DEBUG:     ip 9c06c4d4  sp 930cef48  lr 9bde70ab  pc 9d7ff1d8  cpsr 800f0030
08-24 14:00:12.850 383-383/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
08-24 14:00:12.850 383-383/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000981d8  /data/app/com.nitragames.football.taso2016-1/lib/arm/libgnustl_shared.so (_ZNSs4_Rep8_M_cloneERKSaIcEj+175)
08-24 14:00:14.670 14883-14883/? E/TranscodeReceiver: onReceive : android.intent.action.CHECK_SIOP_LEVEL
08-24 14:00:14.850 1633-2385/? E/NativeCrashListener: Exception dealing with report
    android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
        at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:169)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:230)
        at android.system.Os.read(Os.java:367)
        at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.consumeNativeCrashData(NativeCrashListener.java:240)
        at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.run(NativeCrashListener.java:138)
```

Can you guys help me? Thanks in advance.

Note: encrypt function is working fine and TABLE_PACKENC is being created at first run.